# finding location by point Bing API

Tags: c#, gps, gis, spatial, bing-maps

i'm trying to retrieve a location using point coordinates in Bing Api, i have read the msdn article about finding the location using the point in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx)

and there were an example they used to get the location based on the point, i copied and pasted the url in my chrome browser and got the following error 
"***Access was denied. You may have entered your credentials incorrectly, or you might not have access to the requested resource or operation."***
did microsoft change the api or the URL structure thanks .. BTW that's the [link](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054%20-122.12934?includeEntityTypes=countryRegion&o=xml&key=BingMapsKey) for the API i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a valid Bing API Key to use that service. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx) on how to apply for one.